Is there a minimum midi-chlorian count needed to live?
Is there any information, whether Legends or Canon, that gives a minimum midi-chlorian count possible?

The sad truth is that with today’s super-industrialised ultra-processed Outer Rim diet, none of us are eating nearly enough midi-chlorians.

Master Qui-Gon, what are midi-chlorians?

Qui-Gon explicitly states (in The Phantom Menace) that a zero count is impossible.

Qui-Gon Jinn: Without the midi-chlorians, life could not exist, and we would have no knowledge of the Force.

In The Making of Star Wars, George Lucas (whose views on midi-chlorians has been gloriously inconsistent over the years) stated that a minimum count of one is essential for cell reproduction.

“Midi-chlorians are like a single entity: meaning each one doesn’t
think individually and have a life to itself; they think as a unit
because there’s so many of them and they’re everywhere. They’re in
every single cell [italics added]. And sometimes there’s more than one
in a cell. Sometimes there’s a whole bunch in a cell. But there has to
be at least one in a cell, otherwise the cell can’t reproduce. All
cells. Plant cells. Every life form has a midi-chlorian living inside
of them.”
Star Wars.com News "So What the Heck are midi-chlorians"


Moving down the canon scale, Star Wars: Jedi Master Magazine #1 advises us that the amount normally found in cells is approximately 2500. It doesn't tell us what happens if that amount is lower.


I think that 2500 figure was average, not minimum, but I'd think it's funny if they tested and it returned one, "the Midichlorian count is off the charts" "are you saying they're the chosen one?" "No off the chart as in the Midichlorian count is one" "that's lower than the janitor"

Maybe such a low count would make a person immune to force abilities, 1 could make you the ultimate anti jedi

@Geneworm - You aren't immune to being thrown into a wall or having your head chopped off with a lightsaber
